# Wikipedia API, extract text including links' text

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

I am trying to extract the text from [List of popular music genres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popular_music_genres) Wikipedia article, so that I can check to see what genre a subgenre is under.

I have found some Stack Overflow links describing how to extract the text, but am having difficulty with also getting linked text from the page.

For example:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=List%20of%20popular%20music%20genres
```

will provide me with text from the page, but it does not include any of the subgenres listed under each genre.

Answer (score 0):

Better use [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) with action parse:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=List of popular music genres
```

In addition include `&section=6` to get content only for this section:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=List of popular music genres&section=6
```